# Careers my orders page broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I log into careers I click my account and go to the orders history page.  At first and I've mentioned this in the past why does the my account 'Li' item appear active, its blue although you really have to click on it to display additional data.

In any event the Orders history page did not show our job listing.  Then I realized I had to click one of the other members who placed the order.  So after realizing this I then click an order number only to get a page not found error twice.  So I cannot get any information about our listing, I also am not able to see views by candidate.  Why is the careers site so inconsistent and so buggy.  I know listings are only 350 bucks but seriously there has not been a single time I have successfully used this site without a bug.  The interface is so hard to follow and it seems like just when I found a particular section its nearly impossible to find it again.

Comment: This would be a better bug report, if you included _precise_ methods to reproduce, and got rid of that last bit which is essentially insulting the site.  I mean, I don't see what relevance it has to a bug report; if you have a related gripe that isn't a bug report, there's a tag for that, though I'm pretty sure you'll be met with a worse response.

Comment: I did state how to reproduce.  Log into careers, go to my account.  Click the orders history page. Click an order...this is where the bug happens.  Sorry I just believe the careers site needs a lot more testing and a better us experience.

Comment: I meant UX not us...

Comment: Be that as it may, stating 'the site is inconsistent', 'is buggy every time I use it' is not helpful, you'd be better off deleting it if you expect a positive response.

Comment: Meta is for issues or things that you dislike.  I get feedback about sites that I create that I may not like.  You have to take the advice of others especially other users and try to make the user experience.  Don't take it personal.

Comment: Someone paying for something is a "customer", and entitled to point out issues. That said, it doesn't give the right to have disregard for the entire service just because one or two functions of that service don't work as intended. The question is a little harsh and would get a better response if a little more humble/polite. A grumble may seem to be justified by your frustration, but you're always better just pointing out facts, and constructively listing what is wrong and if it's been like this for some time, etc. (Hint: edit your question ;) )

Comment: I know what meta is for, I'm just saying that pointing out something is buggy, without being specific, comes across as needless noise.  Yes, you've already been specific in regards to the single bug you pointed out; I however am referring to your last few sentences.  As James has said, you would get a better response if you were polite.

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be getting a page not found error when viewing the order. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug has now been fixed. At first we were going to remove the links, I.E. allow admins to see ordering history but not the actual details. Some people thought it was a PCI/PII issue, but we've talked it over and since it's a company account, we're going to allow it.

As far as your UI concerns, it's because when the site first launched we had no capability for "company accounts" or multiple user hierarchies. It was individuals only. Improvements are coming in the future.